# 400 Bad Request: Post Large Data (>65KB)(JSON Format) from android device using WCF Rest service

Tags: android, json, rest, wcf, wcf-binding

I am Posting Data from android to Server Using WCF service in json format. Everything is working fine. I am having issue while I try posting data more than 65KB. But when I post same data using Rest client it is working fine. It is giving issue when posting from android.

I have set all the properties in binding tag to max value. and same in reqderquotas tag. following is my web config setting

```
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Because I am posting files more than 300KB using same service with same web config setting. It is only giving error when posting json

Comment: We cannot see what you are doing. So why do you think we can help?

Comment: @greenapps What you are expecting from me to provide. As it is straight forward question. That I am unable to post data from android to server more than 65KB.

Answer (score 0):

its a common mistake. probably you are setting this at wrong side. if you are receiving more than 65k with soap service you have to increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize`. now be sure both your client and server size increased.

Comment: I have set maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" already but it was not working. It is giving bad request.

Comment: but which side? this client side config file or server side?

Comment: on server side in web.config. I have provided settings in question

Comment: you should set it on client side as i mentioned it on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Request was because of Invalid UTF-8 character not because of large data. I have used following to diagnosed WCF service.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
             switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
             propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```